# macos: different output of arrays truncating in commnad line and bash file

Tags: arrays, macos

The same set of commands gives a different output while run directly on the command window and while written in a file:

```
xxx-MacBook-Air ~ % bash b
a b c
b c b c
xxx-MacBook-Air ~ % all=(a b c); echo ${all[@]}; out=a; all=${all[*]/$out}; echo ${all[@]}
a b c
b c
```

I copied and pasted the same commands from the comand window to the file
for some reason the file while running in addition to truncating the content of the array all also clones it... any advice?

Comment: Maybe include a `cat b` output, so we can be sure that you actually have identical content in there. Also note that `b` is a really bad name: even when doing example code/scripts: use meaningful names.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you're running the script with bash, but your interactive shell is zsh, and they treat arrays differently. Specifically, when you access an array as though it was a plain variable, bash treats it as accessing the first element of the array, but zsh treats it as accessing the entire thing. More specifically, bash treats `all=${all[*]/$out}` as replacing the first element of `all`, but zsh treats it as replacing the entire array (converting it to a plain variable, and effectively deleting the second and third elements).

You can see this more clearly using `declare -p all` to see the result, since that shows whether variable is a plain string or an array, and if it's an array it clearly shows spaces within elements (vs `echo`, which makes them look just like spaces *between* elements). Here's a simple demo, first in bash:

```
$ all=(a b c); all=plainstring; declare -p all
declare -a all='([0]="plainstring" [1]="b" [2]="c")'
```

As you can see, `all=plainstring` only replaced `all[0]`, setting it to "plainstring". Compare that with zsh:

```
% all=(a b c); all=plainstring; declare -p all
typeset all=plainstring
```

Here it's replaced the entire array with a plain string.

BTW, the other common place you see this difference is with `$array` or `${array}` -- zsh expands that to all of the array's elements, but bash only expands it to the first element. If you want the entire array's contents in bash, you need to use `"${array[@]}"` (with double-quotes to keep it from doing silly things to the individual elements).